# Material UI Snackback reloads the page in Functional component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Why changing the state here in the codesandbox here do not reloads/render/paint the page. I have also added comments where i am not understanding

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-nb5ek?file=/demo.js

I did same thing in my case according to the material UI snackbar documentation: The only difference is that i pass the click function to child and invoke from there.

I have created a material UI snackbar in the parent which is a functional component and pass the notification function in Route shown below to the child which is also a functional component.

```
  const [openNotification, setOpenNotification] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
        if (reason === 'clickaway') {
        return;
        }

        setOpenNotification(false);
    };


  const notification = (status) => {
       setOpenNotification(status)
    }

  const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route exact {...rest} render={(props) => (
      <Component {...props} notification={notification}/>
  )} />
)
```

This is the HTML where i am using it in the parent.

```
<Snackbar
            anchorOrigin={{
            vertical: 'bottom',
            horizontal: 'left',
            }}
            open={openNotification}
            autoHideDuration={6000}
            onClose={handleClose}
            message='Success'
            action={
            <React.Fragment>
                <IconButton size="small" aria-label="close" color="inherit" onClick={handleClose}>
                <CloseIcon fontSize="small" />
                </IconButton>
            </React.Fragment>
            }
        />
```

In child i have used the notification function like this in the submit function.

```
function handleSubmit() {
         props.notification(true)
      }
```

Problem: The page renders when the snackbar closes and i dont want it to happen as it just a notification. I know snackbar have a state related to it which is changing from true to false. Although the example over here do not renders the page again from their documentation sandbox when the snackbar closes: https://codesandbox.io/s/5tgvq.
The link to simple snackbar documentation: https://material-ui.com/components/snackbars/

I tried not to use state for it and just make a variable and update it. But then the snackbar wont open even if the value gets true

Comment: I did not understand your exact problem, you mean to say, it is not getting re-route to previous page `/Jobs` until you click on close icon of `snackbar`?

Comment: I removed that line which takes you to previous page. My issue is that as snackbar relies on openNotification state and as it gets changed to true or false. The whole page reloads as state changed. And by default in the material UI snackbar docs, the page do not reloads when they change the state of the snackbar. For example in this codesandbox, i added two comments for my question: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-nb5ek

Comment: ok, you should take that open state inside `<Component/>` to avoid the component reload, basically you need to break the component, (frankly speaking, I am not getting your component hierarchy with provided code, or the way you have provided it )

Comment: from your codesandbox question, `why the page does not reload?`
in your case, you are creating the new `PrivateRoute` on every snackBar state change, as per my knowledge, this will recreate the complete routing again.

Comment: Ok my component hierarchy is this as parent and then child. <Parent>  ------> <Child1> , <Child2>.  Now when anyone submits a form in child 1 for instance. I want to show the snackbar notification in the parent.  Also which i achieved. As i was using <Route> for navigating from one child to another, i passed the notification function in the Route with the props. And now notification function is available in all childs. But after invoking the notification function it changes the state of notification and reloads the page which i do not need,

Comment: can you share complete code of parent, basically I want to see how you are using `ProvateRoute`?
you have to avoid the re-creation of PrivateRoute on every state change as per understanding

Comment: Its broken but i did shared the code,  https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-sanderson-wpm00?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216089/discussion-between-ani-and-harsh-kurra).